# Do i need a certificate for data transmission?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I want to secure transmission of data between my WCF client and service.
I thought i would have to employ an ssl certificate.

[Difference between BasicHttpBinding and WsHttpBinding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36396/Difference-between-BasicHttpBinding-and-WsHttpBind)

However - on this article the user explains the difference between basichttpbinding and wshttpbinding. Wshttpbinding as he shows it has the data encrypted without using certificates.

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't miss anything.

Ssl provides security at the transport level. Which means that it uses https over http but messages are plain, old xmls.

WsBinding is able to provide security at message level. Messages are passed even over http (not https!) but client and server exchange series of xmls which end up with exchanging keys and then the last message of the dialogue is an actual message but encrypted with previously constituted keys.

In both cases, the general principle is the same but the security is constituted at just different levels.

Comment: so why would i go to the bother of using certificates? If i just use wshttpbinding i am secure?

Comment: @user1438082: Maybe. Secure against **what**?

Comment: secure against somebody decrypting messages. Do i need certificates?

Comment: Do, you don't. You can have message level security over http with wsbinding.

Comment: HTTPS is a standard that everyone understands. WS-Binding with message level encryption (which is likely SSL anyways) is completely Microsoft Proprietary. So if you want to interface with, say JAVA, good luck using WS.

Comment: @Aron: WS means that it is the implementation of some of WS-* standards (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Web_service_specifications). It is NOT Microsoft Proprietary. In java you have WSIT for example http://wsit.java.net/

Comment: Why does this site state "The moment you start using authorization, or even authentication, in WCF you have to deal with (X509) certificates. Period. " http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2010/04/09/a-simple-wcf-service-with-username-password-authentication-the-things-you-told-me/

Comment: WS binding CAN do authentication and authorization and it DOES require certificates for this but it DOESN'T require certificates to secure the channel against eavesdropping.